# How execute script from command prompt in python

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I have mysql dump command that I would like to run from from windows shell 
or command prompt. I have used shell it does work.

```
  d= 'BkSql_'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".sql"
  fn = dn+d    
  cmd="""mysqldump -u hapopdy -p   > %s""" %fn
  print cmd
```

Edit:::::::
The -p needs to be a raw input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

If you're running a shell command add `shell=True`

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: `copy` on windows is a shell command, not an executable. Try `subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You should save the password in mysql's local configuration file for the user.(In Unix it's ~/.my.cnf) or you can give it on the command line with `--password=MYPASSWORD`.

Either way, the password will be visible to a large audience. In the .my.cnf case, it will be visible to anyone with read access to the file. In the second case, it will be visible to anyone who can get a process listing on the system, in addition to those who have read access to your script.

Comment: could I create a user that only could dump database/